# UINavigationController and modalViewController problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi I'm having this problem:

I have a UITabBarController with UINavigationControllers in each tab.

However, I'm trying to implement an action that, when I click on a button, should present me a new view with a UINavigationController (since it will be multi-view) in a modal way.

What I've tried is to implement a new UIViewController, with a NavigationBar. And then on the button handler I wrote something like this:

```
SendMessageViewController *v = [[SendMessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SendMessageView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *t = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:v];
[(UINavigationController *)[tabbar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] presentModalViewController:t animated:true]; // hardcoding 0, I know
```

However, the modal view that's pushed appears with 2 navigation bars, one empty, and my other defined on the "SendMessageView" XIB.

Is there a way to solve this? I don't want to create a XIB just to contain a UINavigationController.. I thought I could do it programatically.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is this:

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:t animated:Y];
```

Basically, get a handle to the tab bar ViewController, and then you'll have the single nav bar you were seeking.

Comment: Hi Kendall. Thank for you answer. I've tried your code and it still doesn't work, I still have a double bar showing :( I must be doing something wrong elsewhere :(

Comment: Sorry about that, could have sworn it would work - I know it's possible.